# Issue in tokina 100mm macro aperture on d7200

Tags: tokina

i just bought a second hand tokina 100mm macro for nikon, but when i lock the f to max and lock it and place lens on body everything is fine untill i take firstpic then change the aperture with subdial and try another pic then the viewfinder goes sooo dim, even when i try putting a smaller f like f3 or f4 the viewfinder is soooo dim, when working manually with aperture ring its oerfect, but when the camera is asked to change aperture after first pic the viewfinder is dim. Other lenses which are G lenses works perfectly. Hope my concern is clear

Comment: Hi! I don't think your concern _is_ clear. Does the first picture come out okay?